# How to change src attribute of img element using jquery

Tags: jquery, image

I want to display some images in a img element , on change of  a combo box text. This combo box has some images name and in its value part (means ) file path is stored. I tried using jquery like

```
$("#top_select").change(function(){
var value=$(this).val();
$("#top_img").attr("src",value);

});
```

but, image does not get loaded. 
I stored these filepaths in my db and from there I populated the combo box id=top_select.

browser:explorer 8

Any help?

Comment: can you make a fiddle

Comment: what is the value of the variabel value

Comment: @Neophyte In fiddle I will have to write whole code, but that's not possible. it will take much time. please provide me help.

Comment: what is the jQuery version? try to change .attr with .prop

Comment: Can you past more of your code because I have used your code and it's working for me.

Comment: @Arun value has the file path received from database.

Comment: Where do u store your image file ? your image path ??

Comment: @hizbul I store the images in a folder on desktop.and i store the file path in my db,so that I can load the image according to the path.

Comment: right, so did you get right path from : console.log(value); ??

Comment: how does your image path looks like. If it's like file:///C:/ then I don't think it will work.

Comment: @Mark this is the file path c:\Documents and Settings\edge\Desktop\Top_folder\top1.png

Answer (score 0):

The code you are using is correct. Check the browser error console if there any erros.

Or else you can this alternative

```
 $("#top_select").change(function(){
    var value=$(this).val();
$("#img_holder").html('<img src="'+value+'" />');
    });
```

Make sure you are getting the image path correctly

Comment: check the alert(value) to make sure you are getting the image path.

Comment: when I checked the console (F12),it shows the correct file path.but image is not loaded into <img>.

Comment: @edge do you see anything in your img src

Comment: @Mark <img id="top_img" style="border-bottom: #000 1px solid; position: absolute; border-left: #000 1px solid; width: 500px; height: 460px; border-top: #000 1px solid; top: 50px; border-right: #000 1px solid; left: 590px;" src="C:\Documents and Settings\edge\Desktop\TOP_FOLDER\top3.PNG" complete="complete" jQuery1102013761661523156682="3"/>

Answer (score 0):

try this out:

```
  $("#top_select").change(function (e) {
    var file = this.files;
    readImage(file,function(event){
       $("#top_img").attr("src", event.target.result); 
     });
  });

function readImage(input, callback) {
    if (input && input[0]) {
       var FR = new FileReader();

       FR.readAsDataURL(input[0]);
       FR.onload = callback;
   }
}
```